# LTspice: SEPIC simulated output voltage does not match known output voltage

Tags: ltspice, sepic

I am designing a SEPIC that meets the following criteria:

➢ Vin = 15 V-35 V
➢ Vout = 25 V
➢ Output voltage ripple 1% peak to peak
➢ Switching frequency 100 kHz
➢ Load 10 W-50 W

Calculations have been done for each component with the circuit as follows:

[image]

The simulation for the output voltage is as follows, showing the Vin(min) of 15 V in blue, 25V in red, and max of 35 V in cyan.

However, both inputs are supposed to have a voltage output of 25 V ± 1% ripple (pk-pk). I am unsure where I have gone wrong and am also not confident about the usefulness of my step parameter in achieving anything. It is not mentioned in the brief that a step parameter even needs to be used.

[image]

Other potentially relevant info:

Duty cycle D_1 for 15 V input = 0.63
Duty cyle D_1 for 35 V input = 0.42

So, D_1 adjustable from 0.42 - 0.63.

Resistance was taken from calculation using highest load, 50 W.

T_on = 5.83 μs.

I can provide other specific values/calculations I used as required.

Comment: Why is your input voltage not plain ordinary DC? Please provide a plot on a white background with axes characters that are big enough to read without a magnifying glass. Why do you talk about "both inputs"? Is there another input that you haven't shown?

Comment: @Andyaka I thought it was. I have the value input in "DC value", is that not it? In the design criteria, the circuit is supposed to take an input range of 15V-35V, and I've gathered that the Vout is to be 25V regardless. It seems I have not done it correctly and that is also what I seek advice for.

Comment: If you don't adjust the duty cycle sure, you'll get this happening. You say T-on is 5.83 μs and, I suspect this remains the case for all three scenarios. Thanks for making the image clearer.

Comment: 1n914 should not be a little too "low"?

Comment: @Antonio51 which part is too low?

Comment: 1n914 is only a few hundred mA ... Shouldn't 2 A minimum pass into the load?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I am unsure where I have gone wrong*

The problem is that you are not correctly adjusting the duty cycle when the stepping occurs. For a 15 volt DC input I get 25 volts on the output with a duty of 0.628: -

[image]

And, if I raised the input voltage to 35 volts I'd get 25 volts out when the duty cycle was 0.412: -

[image]

Hopefully, you can see that this works and learn how to correctly adjust duty cycle. I also expect that my duty cycles are a little different to yours because I didn't set my maximum timestep to anything special.

However, what you might want to do is close the loop and let the duty cycle find its own level for the output voltage of 25 volts irrespective of the input voltage: -

[image]

I haven't particularly tried to set the control loop be fast. I've just bludgeoned in some values that I knew would result in a soft start and steady control.

Comment: I am unsure how to actually add the respective duty cycles to the circuit as you have done for each voltage input.

Comment: @eutectic_codswallop in your pulse generator you have the on time. That is representing your duty cycle when compared with the period (10 us). So, 5.83 us in 10 us is a duty cycle of 0.583.

Comment: Ah right, of course.

Comment: @eutectic_codswallop I'll also add that you can get a much smoother output voltage by choosing better valued inductors and capacitors. Maybe ask that in a new post if you are interested in pursuing that. If we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.